# How to join two tables while removing repeated entries in one column of one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm not very familiar with SQL and have hit a problem with duplicate-removal that I need some help with.

I have two tables as follows:

```
config -> ID  -----------
       -> timestamp      |
       -> vcsID          |
       -> platform       |
                         |
data   -> ID             |
       -> configID <-----
       -> value
```

For each row in the config table there may be multiple rows in the data table, the join being:

```
data.configID = config.ID
```

However, in the config table there may be  entries in which vcsID has not advanced (these represent builds on the same code from our version control system, and 'value' represents a build metric such as memory size); they are not duplicate rows, because the timestamp will be different, but I need to get rid of them.  I want to create a view on the data that removes these duplicates.  How do I go about doing that? In MySQL I can do the following:

```
select *
from (select * from config group by vcsID) as filtered
inner join data
on data.configID = filtered.ID
```

...but Postgres is strictly compliant with the SQL standard and requires that anything in the Select clause must be in the Group By clause so I can't get the ID field out of the sub-query to do the join.

As an example, some sample data might be:

```
config
ID    timestamp     vcsID   platform
1   1/1/2014 09:00    18       "x"
2   1/1/2014 20:20    30       "y"
3   1/1/2014 20:25    30       "y"
4   1/1/2014 20:40    31       "y"

data
ID  configID   value
12      1      40000
13      2       125
14      3       125
15      4       130
```

...and, taking platform "y" as the thing I'm interested in, what I'd like to get out is:

```
               config                 |         data
ID    timestamp     vcsID  platform   |  ID  configID value
2   1/1/2014 20:20    30      "y"     |  13      2     125
4   1/1/2014 20:40    31      "y"     |  15      4     125
```

or, equivalently:

```
               config                 |         data
ID    timestamp     vcsID  platform   |  ID  configID value
3   1/1/2014 20:25    30      "y"     |  14      3     125
4   1/1/2014 20:40    31      "y"     |  15      4     125
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To get the `ID` out, just change to `from (select vcsID from config group by vcsID)`.  To get the rest of the columns do a second join (third table) to config joining on configID.

Comment: You can use min or max of a value if you don't want it in the the group by -- this used to drive me nuts when I transitioned from MySQL to Postgres, though I now regard it as a very good thing. You can also do what you want with table expressions using row_number() over() and partition by.

Comment: @paqogomez: I see that I can remove the duplicates by using `from (select vcsID from config group by vcsID)` but the vcsID field isn't in the data table, it is the config.ID field that links to data.configID.  Without getting the config.ID out how do I join the two?  I guess what you might be saying is that we have to redesign the schema so that vcsID goes in the data table also.

Comment: @John Barça: how would I use min() and max() to remove the duplicates though?

Comment: Your comment that postgres is more strict and you need all columns in the group by, well, you can use min/max for those that you don't want in group by and use group by on everything else to get a unique combination. Table expressions are cleaner, but harder to get your head round initially.

Comment: `data.ID = config.ID`? Contradicts the table definition. I assume you mean `data.configID = config.ID`?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter, yes, sorry, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (vcsID) *
FROM   config c
JOIN   data   d ON d.configID = c.ID
ORDER  BY vcsID, "timestamp" DESC;
```

Assuming you want to pick the latest row from each group of identical `vcsID`, thus the `ORDER BY`. If you really don't care which row you get for each `vcsID`, you don't need `ORDER BY`. Either way, the leading columns in `ORDER BY` have to match `DISTINCT ON` expressions, so you cannot `ORDER BY c.id`, like you seem to want. You'd need to wrap this in a sub-query and order in the outer query.

Detailed explanation for `DISTINCT ON` and alternative solutions:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Aside: don't use basic type names like `timestamp` as identifiers.

Comment: That's the answer!  DISTINCT ON () is my new favourite phrase :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

select distinct on (vscID) *
from config c 
join data d on d.configID = c.ID
where c.platform = "y"

It should give you what you are looking for. The "distinct on (column...)" removes duplicates based on specific column(s).